# Handling Page lifecycle events

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am a VB.NET Developer trying to learn C# in my spare time.  Please see the code below:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += Form1_Load;//event handler code
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string test = "got here";
        }

    }
```

This is a Windows Form app.  If I add the event handler code to the constructor then Form1_Load handles the load event.

Now see the Web Forms app below:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s = "got here";
        }
    }
```

Page_Load is fired without any event handler code?

My question is: Are Page Life Cycle events automatically wired to function names e.g. Page_Load automatically handles the page load in c# ASP.NET? Why does this not apply to Windows Forms? Where do you put the Event Handler code in windows forms? the .designer?

Comment: My opinion, start learning asp.net for web like you do not know anything about desktop programming - and do not try to compare that two... the idea is totally something different.

Comment: "... in my spare time" - do yourself a favor and skip WebForms. Go to http://asp.net and the MVC tutorials there.

Comment: If you're going to learn a new technology, don't learn the one that's on its way out the door. @HenkHolterman has the right idea - learn ASP.NET MVC and keep up with modern development practices.

Comment: It is not web forms I am learning.  It is c#.  I am competent using mvc4 and web forms, however most of my experience is vb.net.

Comment: Well, the question was entirely about a WebForms feature, not really about C#.

Answer (score 1):

In Asp.Net you can set AutoEventWireup value. Please check this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324151

However when I need to handle an event the easiest way for me is going to the aspx source view, find the the **runatserver** control and specify my handler there. For example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomer" runat="server" />
```

As you type "on..." the list of events is shown (events are identified by ray icon), select OnLoad and Create.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomer" OnLoad="txtCustomer_Load" runat="server" />
```

Now go to your cs code behind file and you'll see default handler was created there.

```
protected void txtCustomer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Another option is going to Design View, right click on the control and go to properties. Click on the ray icon and add your handler.

Answer (score 0):

Winform do not auto fire event as Asp.Net because winform has not page life Cycle.
To handle a event in winform, you select a component in design mode. Look at the right panel, you will see the events tab. There are alot event here. Double click to handle it.
[image]